# Why am I getting an error on findViewbyID?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm getting an error at `(R.id.editText);`, and `(R.id.button);` I've never gotten this error before and I don't understand what's up? The error is: "cannot resolve symbol 'editText'" and "cannot resolve symbol 'button'"

```
EditText editText;
Button button;

String playerName = "";

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference playerRef;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_name);

    editText = findViewById (R.id.editText);
    button = findViewById (R.id.button);
```

Comment: "An error"? "This error"? What error?

Comment: Do you mean a compile error?

Comment: Do you not need to cast the return value of `findViewById` to `EditText`?

Comment: @user959631 not for many years now, no.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `activity_enter_name.xml` and check if you have corresponding IDs - `editText` & `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Use id attribute for your edittext and button

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```